# Push Notification not working for android

Tags: google-apps, salesforce-sdk-android

I am working on an android project that utilizes the Salesforce Mobile SDK. I have recently implemented Push notification, this was working fine till Dec 19, 2019 firebase update.

https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#december_19_2019

After this update, Salesforce is unable to send push notification messages to the connected app. I have tried to send message from other servers/firebase API and it works fine, this only occurs when sending from Salesforce.

Below is an error screenshot when sending a message from connected app.

[image]

I have already raised this error to the Mobile SDK team and they asked me to raise it to salesforce.

I have tried with the SF SDK vanilla app and implemented Push notification and getting the same issue there too.

Am I missing anything?

Can I get any help?

Thanks!

Manish Kumar

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue, their server key needs to update in Salesforce.

Below link was useful to resolve the issue.

https://help.moengage.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002937886-Getting-Google-Authentication-Error-while-sending-Mobile-Push-notifications